# What does str[i] - 'a' mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

If we were to be iterating through a string str, and inside the for loop was a line like `str[i] - 'a'`... what does that exactly mean? `str[i]` would be returning a character from the `string str`, and then we would be subtracting `'a'` from it? I'm just confused by that.

Comment: `str[i] - 'a'` means `str[i] - 97`. If we assume that `str[i]` is letter between `a` and `z` then result is number 0...25.

Comment: `x - y` evaluates to the value of the operand `-` applied to the two values.  That is, `y` subtracted from `x`.  `str[i] - 'a'` evaluates to the value of `'a'` subtracted from `str[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ASCII (or any encoding in which lowercase letters are in a compact sequence) it is the number (starting at 0) of the lowercase letter in `str[i]` (the `i`th position in `str`).

*Very* bad coding, unless you are absolutely sure it is a lowercase letter, and not e.g. LATIN-1 or some other 8-bit encoding in which you have lowercase letters like 'ñ' or 'á' or even 'ß' which are strewn about the high --first bit one-- space).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) The bracket operator [] of the std::string type returns a reference to a char.

Since (signed) char can be natively interpreted by the compiler as an 8-bit signed integer in the range -128 to 127, then all due mathematical operations can be made.

**An example** of common use AFAIK: subtracting or operating with chars on a (text) string can be used for adding salt to some cryptography algorithm.

Comment: @PeteBecker • range -128 to 127.  (Previous standard, -127 to 127, for 1s complement machines.)

Comment: I corrected the answer. Thank you @PeteBecker.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree. Not sure why I put it there, now re-reading the question. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Just a minor point: `char` has to be **at least** 8 bits. It can be larger. Some DSPs are strictly 32-bit, so `char` has to be 32 bits. Just something to file away in the back of your mind. +1.